# origin keyword is git

Tags: git, github, version-control

I found people do `push origin branchName` after they do `git checkout -b branchName`. I use push without origin, what's the point of using the origin keyword here? I know it means remote, but I do `git push` it still pushed my code to my remote branch.

Answer (score -1):

`origin` is just the most common word for your Git server. This can be services such as [GitHub](https://github.com), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/overview), or even a custom Git server. To answer your question basically people are just being explicit in saying push to this Git server. You can have multiple Git servers other then `origin`. If you use multiple Git servers this would allow you to define which server you want to push to. `origin` is just the common name for the default server and normally it's set to be the default Git server in your repo.

Comment: what else can be the value to 'replace' origin?

Comment: Anything. It's just the name assigned to the Git server. https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/. Gives some more information about adding a remote. In that example `origin` is the name of the server. You can change that to whatever you want. But `origin` is just the most common.